# Qt Quick how to create a button that will loock native to each OS app is used in?

Tags: c++, qt, button, qml

What I need is simple: qml way to create a button that would loock native on each platform app is compiled to? (mainly I wonder about linux, windows and Mac OS X)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built-in.

But there is a project called Qt Quick Components, mainly for mobile platforms. There is also some development for desktop platforms, see http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

There may not have been anything built-in when you asked this question, but [QtQuick.Controls 1.0](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qmlmodule-qtquick-controls1-qtquick-controls-1-0.html) was officially released as a part of Qt 5.1. It has a [Button](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-button.html) component that should tries to match the native look and feel.

The QtQuick.Controls module is basically the Qt Desktop Components project that blakharaz linked to in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720914/331041). It just has a new name, is more developed and is better integrated now.